# How well does IronPython 2.6 integrate with ADO.NET Entities?

Tags: entity-framework, ironpython

If I were to write an application in IronPython 2.6, how easy would it be to use ADO.NET Entities as the DAL?  Can anyone point to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.simonsegal.net/blog/2010/02/06/ironpython-and-the-entity-framework-part-50-concluded/), the answer is no.

It looks like you can write your entire DAL in, say, C#, and call those methods from IronPython, but there won't be any linq support in IronPython.